# How to be able to apply a filter to my dataTable that also looks inside an object to filter the data

Tags: angular, datasource, mat-table

I am trying to filter an array with objects currently the TaskTeam isn't filtering because it only looks at tTaskName and doesn't go to the TeamName.

[image]

```
 <MainGridDto>
    <tTaskTeam>
    <TeamName>GLS - rest of GE Businesses</TeamName>
    <pk_TaskTeam>17</pk_TaskTeam>
    </tTaskTeam>
    </MainGridDto>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="value"  placeholder="Search Filter By Name, or Owner"> 
        <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="applyFilter(''); value=''">
          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
        </mat-form-field>
```

This is how I get my data:

```
 getTaskService(){
    this.service.getAllMainGrid().subscribe((data) => {

  this.isLoading = false;
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource <AllMainGridInterface> (data as AllMainGridInterface[]);
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

 }, error => this.isLoading = false);
  }
```

This is where it applys the user input that applys the filter to filter the data.

```
 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();  
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

Comment: Please focus on the **minimal** part of a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Maryannah is that better? I took away things that weren't really needed. I am just trying to filter an array with an object.